# Cannot see my products on my products page in django

Tags: python-3.x

I'm following the 6 hr. tutorial on Python, from YouTube.

I'll preface by saying I've got the latest django version. He's using 2.6 i'm unsure if that could be an issue. The information I've found on django sites state that the syntax is exactly the same.

Link here: https://youtu.be/_uQrJ0TkZlc?t=21350

Time stamp is where I'm stuck, I'll include the code below and its verbatim what he's typing yet when my products page comes up, I see the  header however no listed products in my page. I've created 5 from the django created admin webpage. I'm not really sure where to go from here, I've racked my head and cannot seem to figure out what I did wrong.

> views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products:': products})


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse("New Products!")
```

> index.html

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I included the code in the above box its my first time here, and I've only been coding for about a week. If you want to consider tutorial following coding.

Comment: Can you print the value of products in the index function?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried and no, I could not. I feel there is something wrong with the syntaxes but everywhere I looked it is correct. I'm sorry I drive 18 wheelers for a living and can rarely answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look below you'll see the typo that I had created myself due to lack of attention to detail, I hope this doesn't happen to those in the future but I've solved my own issue.

There is a ":" within the 3rd argument for the render request ""{'products":"' : in products} this simple simicolon was the issue to my problems.

> View.py

```
def index(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'products:': products})
```